# Nativescript calendar plugin

Tags: calendar, nativescript

Can anyone tell me how to use the calendar plugin in nativescript? And I am using only XML not with typescript. I need the calendar control exactly like as in Bookmyshow.

Comment: what is calendar? Do you mean date picker? If yes, you can take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-timedatepicker

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for calendar plugin.

The most extended one is the [telerik-ui for NativeScript](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction)
The calendar is highly customisable and offers a lof of functionality.
You can see more about it here - keep in mind that this is a paid functionality.

Another option is to search for community-made nativescript calendar related plugins. Like [this one here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-calendar)! Not familiar with it - it looks easy to work with.

The third option is to use date-picker. IF you are looking for a calendar in Android then you can open your ***app/App_Resources/Android/values-21*** folder and open the file styles.xml and modify the default mode of the date picker from ***spinner*** to ***calendar***.

Example:

```
<item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the "**Telerik UI for NativeScript**" plugin. There is a [free](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui) and [pro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui-pro) version which contains a really slick looking and functioning calendar UI component.

More details about the plugins and their contents can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction). Additionally you can take a look at the sdk examples regarding the RadCalendar component for both [vanila](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/tree/release/sdk/app/calendar) and [Angular 2](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/release/sdkAngular/app/calendar) NativeScript.

Comment: Thanks . It is very helpful . Can I get any code project for nativescript-telerik calendar???

Comment: Please refer the links I added to my response above ("look at the sdk examples regarding the RadCalendar component for both vanila and Angular 2 NativeScript")

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-calendar

```
"nativescript-calendar": "^1.0.7",
```

Answer (score 0):

I juss created a wrapper over android-lib which help in rendering calendar in nativescript. checkout the plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-calendar-weekview

[image: Calendar 7 Day Week View]